# Specific question on devices should be closed and deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Regarding the question "[Which devices might help against an attack?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/6544/82)"…  I consider this question a prime example of a bad question:

1. It is a [shark vs gorilla](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).
2. It asks for a *list of things*.
3. It shows an *utter ignorance of the law*. The law varies so much in location that any answer will be utterly useless in another local.
4. It is overly broad as it aims to cover *all possible devices*, not just weapon but any device that could potentially be used…
5. It has **nothing** to do with martial arts whatsoever. It is asking about "devices" without any consideration to martial arts whatsoever.

*Why is this question not closed and deleted?*

So, I have been keeping an eye on this and vote to close seem to vanish! What gives?

Comment: If you and @MacacoBranco want to close it, then why haven't either of you voted?

Comment: @LemmyX I stopped using SE due to how it abuses its users.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Any change about that? Any progress?

Comment: @LemmyX Not as far as I know… Some noise, no action.

Answer (score 3):

The moment you cast a close vote the question appears in the review queue. The only thing is that you'll have to be prepared for the community to disagree, or possibly not agree quickly enough therefore the close vote ages away.

I will make a couple of small points:

> It shows an utter ignorance of the law.

IMVHO this is not sufficient to close a question - unless the OP is intentionally discussing breaking what should be obvious laws in most jurisdictions (i.e. outright assault or worse). It's a given that none of us are lawyers and even if one was then you are only licensed to practice in a specific region. If "the law" is going to be used as a close reason then most self defense related questions will be closed, we will be restricted to academic explanations of history and techniques and patterns. It is up to each reader and practitioner to ensure that they comply with the law where practicable.

> It has nothing to do with martial arts whatsoever.

It is directly related to self defense, at this point in time the community hasn't deemed self defense to be outside the scope of martial arts (it's been discussed, but other than agreeing that many self defense questions are messy nothing else solid has really eventuated).

Other than that you have some valid points, the question is broad and does ask for a list of things. However since the author has put a reasonable amount of effort in I would suggest that people help him bring it more on topic. Alternatively many people here have edit privileges so they can help shape the question (it is currently in the [review queue here](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/close/4280)).

Comment: The ignorance of the law has more to do with the fact that no laws apply in all locals, so some self defence device that is legal in X might get you to jail in Y. This makes the best answer dependent on where you live hence too localised to be of any use.

Comment: Sirens, Tactical light with strobing, Pepperspray, Stun guns, and Elektronics are all listed as "devices". I would be surprise if a martial art school uses any of those in their daily training. Thus my comment on having nothing to do with martial arts.

Comment: Just for the record: there are schools that use "devices" in training. Which ones, depends of course. In one school I attended, we used knifes (wood). Another we used plastic bags and ropes (defending against suffocation).

Comment: @Sardathrion-againstSEabuse : I think that krav maga uses some of those things, but probably for teaching defenses against, not using them as an offense.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more of a symbolic gesture than anything else at this point, but I agree that this ought to be closed. It's a very general list/opinion question, and we obviously didn't do a very good job at guiding the querent to a better question (although they are still active on Stack Overflow, so all is not lost).

Comment: If you see questions you think should be closed, by all means vote to close!

Comment: Also, it looks like we had 4 votes to close before, but did not make it to 5.

Comment: You should vote to close it if you think that it should be closed. I will vote too.